# How do I change permissions on a file with 075 permissions?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, nfs

I have an NFS share mounted on a Linux machine.

I have folders in this share that have somehow gotten 075 permissions set to them, though the files contained within are still 775.

When I try to change the permissions of these files, I receive the error:

> ```
> chmod: changing permissions of '[filename]': Operation not permitted
> ```

`ls -l` from the 'top level directory' gives this:

```
d---rwxr-x    2 root          mygroup          4 Dec  1 04:16 folder
```

while the command `ls -l` within the `folder` brings up:

```
-rwxrwxr-x    1 myuser mygroup 134756 Nov 28 06:04 filename
```

I've tried `sudo chown`, `chmod` and even just `sudo su` then `chmod` and `chown` to try to change these permissions.  Both `root` and `myuser` are part of `mygroup`, so I'm really at a loss as to what to do here.  Everything I try to google on this comes up as Windows problems or people trying to delete files they don't have access to for school or something.  I have full admin access to these files, I have baremetal access to the VM, etc, and I just want to organize my files.

Comment: What is running on the server with the share? it looks to me as though the problem is with share permissions on the server, although your group permissions should mean that you should be able to do all you need to do without owner access.

Comment: Is the device mounted rw?

Comment: The device is mounted rw.  I can read and write to other files just fine.  I was also able to change the name of the folder without a problem, but I can't modify contents of the folder.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by what is running on the server with the share.  This share runs multiple docker containers, all of the services on those containers run with the same UID and GID of the user/group, but the share itself is mounted on the host VM, and the folders needed for the various containers are mounted as volumes.  The share is from a FreeNas server I also control.